# How to make a newcommand producing a matrix

Tags: macros, matrices

I would like to do something like this

```
\newcommand{\pmat}[1][2][3][4]{\begin{pmatrix} #1 & #2 \\ #3 & #4\end{pmatrix}}
```

But this produces the error

```
ERROR: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
...                                              
l.42 \newcommand{\pmat}[1][2][3
                               ][4]{\begin{pmatrix} #1 & #2 \\ #3 & #4\end{p..
```

How do I create a newcommand \pmat such that `\pmat{1}{2}{3}{4}` produces `\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4\end{pmatrix}`?

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because the proper syntax is

```
\newcommand{\pmat}[4]{\begin{pmatrix} #1 & #2 \\ #3 & #4\end{pmatrix}}
```

The argument between the brackets is the number of arguments, not the argument's name.

Comment: Thanks! I had the feeling that I was just missing something elementary

Answer (score 5):

The syntax for `\newcommand` (without optional argument) is

```
\newcommand{\<name>}[<number of arguments>]{<definition>}
```

so you can use

```
\newcommand{\pmat}[4]{%
  \begin{pmatrix} #1 & #2 \\ #3 & #4\end{pmatrix}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\pmat[4]{\ensuremath{\begin{pmatrix} #1 & #2 \\ #3 & #4\end{pmatrix}}}

\begin{document}
\pmat{1}{2}{3}{4}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it a best practice to use `\ensuremath`?